# ADO Error exception handling?

Tags: delphi, ado, bde, c++builder-xe4

I just switched from using the BDE to ADO by replacing the Tables and Queries to its equivalent in ADO components.

I'm always execute the query inside try...catch like this:

```
//Fdm is Data Module
//TEndOfDay is TTable
//QEndOfDay is TQuery

Screen->Cursor = crSQLWait;
Fdm->QEndOfDay->SQL->Add("SELECT * FROM TEndOfDay");
try{
  Fdm->QEndOfDay->ExecSQL();
  Fdm->QEndOfDay->Open();
  Screen->Cursor = crDefault;
}
catch (EDBEngineError &DBEngineError){
  strError = DBEngineError.Message;
  Screen->Cursor = crDefault;
}
catch (EDatabaseError &DatabaseError){
  strError = DatabaseError.Message;
  Screen->Cursor = crDefault;
}
catch(...){
  strError = "Error";
  Screen->Cursor = crDefault;
}
```

Since I switched to ADO, does those exceptions (DBEngineError, DatabaseError) are applicable?

I have been edited my post to include Delphi folks, they are responds quickly. No matter if the answer in Delphi code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first check for [`EADOError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Win.ADODB.EADOError), which are specific ADO-related exceptions, and then [`EDatabaseError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.EDatabaseError), which are more general database exceptions. `EDBEngineError` is an old BDE exception class, and is not applicable any longer if you're not using the BDE.

```
Screen.Cursor := crSQLWait;
Fdm.QEndOfDay.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM TEndOfDay';
try
  try
    Fdm.QEndOfDay.Open;
  except
    on E: EAdoError do
    begin
      // ADO specific error handling
    end;
    on E: EDatabaseError do
    begin
      // Generic database error handling
    end;
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      // Other exceptions (non-DB related)
    end;
  end;
finally
  // Revert cursor to default always.
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Ken, and I appreciate your reply.