# does ADO has Record/Key deleted Error?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i am working on Delphi 7+ SQL server.

i am converting my application from BDE to ADO.
and in  some places they are handling **Record/Key deleted** error and the error code they are checking for is **8708**.

do we have Record/Key deleted Error in ADO? and can any one please explain me in what scenario it will raise that error?

Comment: i am using DBGRID, TQUERY,TDATASOURCE,DBNAVIGATOR. yes i want to reproduce the same in BDE application so i can replicate the same error in ADO and i can do error handling for that.

Comment: @MartynA: i want to handle Record/Key deleted error in ADO and i want to know the error code for that. if i am able to create Record/key deleted error in BDE i can work on smililar example in ADO and i can do error handling.

Comment: @MartynA: i have edited my question. Can you please check now?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the section Resolviing Update Conflicts in http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+15+Working+with+ADO/Updating+the+Data/

Comment: I'm not sure that ADO has an 8708 type exception.  See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868588/ado-error-exception-handling which suggest checking EAdoError, then EDatabaseError..you're going to need to familiarize yourself with ADO and its exception objects before diving into replacing existing exception handlers, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The following may help you exploring how to reconcile update conflicts in Sql Server tables
using TAdo* components.  By way of preparation, create a table on your server with a definition like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATable](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [name] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
  [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and then populate it with a few rows.

Then, create a minimal Ado Delphi project with a TBGrid and TDNNavigator and the code below.

**Update** If you have read the original version of my answer to your q,
it talked in terms of doing batch updates on the dataset.  However, since posting it, I've discovered what seems to be an anomaly in how 
`TAdoQuery.UpdateBatch` works, so I've simplified the example code
to avoid using batched updates.

Now, compile and run the project, and open a second instance of it in a CMD window.
Change the [name] field in a row in the 2nd instance and save it, then try and make
a different change to the same row in the IDE instance.  You should get an error
with words to the effect of

> Record cannot be located for updating.  Some values may have changed since was
>   last read.

How you deal with this condition is entirely up to you.  You could, for example, save a local copy of the current user's version of the row's
fields, cancel the edit to the row and then fetch the new row version from the server and ask the user
whether his changes should be applied to it.

YOu should see that when the error occurs, the NativeError code is 32.  Unfortunately, that is also the NativeError returned when the second 
instance of the app deletes the record rather than changes it (which
makes sense in a way, because in either case, the original version
of the record no longer exists in the server table.  If you want to be
able to distinguish between rows that have been changed  and ones that
have been deleted, you could e.g. run a query against the table to 
see if the row with the current row ID exists.

Code

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure OnException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnException := OnException;
  AdoQuery1.LockType := ltOptimistic;
  AdoQuery1.CursorType := ctKeySet;
  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from atable';
  AdoQuery1.Open;
  DBGrid1.Options := DBGrid1.Options + [dgEditing];
  DBGrid1.Columns[0].ReadOnly := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
var
  AErrors : Errors;
  AError : Error;
  i : Integer;
  S : String;
begin
  Caption := 'Exception';
  if E is EDatabaseError then begin
    AErrors := AdoQuery1.Connection.Errors;
    for i := 0 to AErrors.Count - 1 do begin
      AError := AErrors.Item[i];
      S := Format('Number: %d, NativeError: %d, source: %s, description: %s',
        [AError.Number, AError.NativeError, AError.Source, AError.Description]);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: @kobik: Originally I did, yes, thanks for pointing it out.  However, as I've mentioned in my update, since posting my answer I've noticed what seems to be an anomaly in `TCustomAdoDataSet.UpdateBatch` so I've re-done my answer to avoid batched updates.  I will look into that a bit later because I'm not sure whether it's a genuine anomaly or just me having a "senior moment".

Comment: @kobik, thanks, but that wasn't the anomaly I've run into.  Once I've got it clear in my head, I may try and explain.